# How to firestore get the docs with lowest value in an array and orderby then lowest value first

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing sorting out my category of product with the Low to High price.

How to firestore get the docs with lowest value in an array and orderby then lowest value.

[image]

```
            snapshot = await FS.collection(FSName.product)
            .orderBy("variants", "asc")
            .where("variants", "array-contains", "price")
            .limit(numOfProducts)
            .get()
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you're attempting isn't possible, because you can't target values within objects within arrays for array-contains.  If you want to order or filter by some document value, that value has to be in a field that isn't within an object in an array.

If your variants array contains only one item, you will need to move that item outside of an array into a dedicated field.

If your variants array contains mulitiple items, you will need to move those items to another collection, and query that collection separately to find the item with the lowest price.